# Using the Azure cli to automate the creation of Diagnostic Settings for resources

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Method:

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings create --resource $resourceId -n $name --event-hub $eventHub --logs '[ { "category": "WorkflowRuntime", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": { "enabled": false, "days": 0 } } ]' --metrics '[ { "category": "WorkflowRuntime", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": { "enabled": false, "days": 0 } } ]
```

Expectation

Creates a Diagnostic setting for the specified resource as identified by the resourceId

Actual

```
(BadRequest) Metric category 'WorkflowRuntime' is not supported, supported categories are: 'Capacity;Transaction'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, the resource does not have the log category. In fact, the different resource type has different log categories. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=CMD).

[image]

If you want to get available categories for one resource, you can use the following command

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings categories list --resource <resource id>
```